# What is a good way to push firebase chat notification to mobile app user?

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, chat

I am working on a project where flutter is used for mobile app development, spring boot for server-side implementation, and firebase for storing chat conversations and push notifications.

There is a chat functionality in our project and we want to push notification to User B when User A sends a message to User B. **Please help me to understand the cons of the following approaches in order to implement this functionality**. Please take **performance and price** these 2 factors under consideration.

When User A sends a message to User B,

1. Mobile APP calls server's API with User B's id, then server pushes a notification to User B using B's FCM token.
2. Server attaches **addChildEventListener** at the start-up of an application and listens to the firebase real-time database whenever a new message arrives, it detects and pushes a notification to the User B. Here is the documentation link:
   https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#java_7
3. Cloud function to deliver push notification to User B.

Comment: Just call a cloud function from the app when a message is sent (you probably only want to do this when the recipient is not in the chat). The cloud function then sends the FCM notification. Cloud functions are charged for but only after 2 million or so in a month afaik. Check their charges.

Comment: @GrahamD can you shed some light on limitations on the 1st and 2nd approaches? because they seem free to use, so will there be a performance issue if I chose from 1st or 2nd over the cloud function?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'server pushes a notification'. Do you think the rtdb will do that on its own? It won't. You need to write code.

Comment: @GrahamD server will push notifications using firebase admin sdk.

Comment: So you have to have your own app server to put the sdk on and you still have to  write code (in node.js, Java, etc) to build and send the message. I do not have my own servers so can't comment on this method.